# Parse/Save file from Spring Server. I am trying to hit the endpoints in Postman

Tags: java, spring, file, postman

Here is my controller class:

```
package com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.controllers;// FileController.java
import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.entities.MapDataEntity;
import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.respositories.MapDataRepository;
import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.services.FileParserService;
import com.example.justin_fulkerson_project.util.FixedLengthField;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/files")
public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    private FileParserService fileParserService;

    @Autowired
    private MapDataRepository mapDataRepository;

    private String saveUploadedFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        // Generate a unique filename
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();

        // Define the directory where the file will be saved
        String uploadDir = "uploads";

        // Create the upload directory if it doesn't exist
        File directory = new File(uploadDir);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }

        // Save the file to the upload directory
        Path filePath = Paths.get(uploadDir, fileName);
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), filePath);

        // Return the absolute path of the saved file
        return filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    }


    @PostMapping("/parse")
    public List<Map<String, String>> parseFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestBody Map<String, FixedLengthField> fields) throws IOException {
        String filePath = saveUploadedFile(file); // Save the uploaded file and get its path
        return fileParserService.parseFixedLengthFile(filePath, fields);
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public void saveParsedData(@RequestBody List<Map<String, String>> parsedData) {
        for (Map<String, String> record : parsedData) {
            MapDataEntity mapDataEntity = new MapDataEntity();
            mapDataEntity.setData(record);
            mapDataRepository.save(mapDataEntity);
        }
    }

    // Implement other endpoints as needed
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-03-16T19:44:49.636+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/api/files/save"
}
```

Does this have to do with the data in my file? I am trying to hit the endpoint with json data.

This is the data in my file:

```json
[
  {"firstName": "Justin", "lastName": "Fulkerson"},
  {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried uploading both .txt data and .json data.

Here are my logs for the error:

```
2024-03-16T13:19:21.346-07:00  WARN DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

Comment: In Postman, make sure Body is "raw" and the type dropdown (that appears when you pick "raw") is "JSON".  From the error it looks like you've selected "form-data" for body type.